# Playing sounds with C++?

Tags: c++, audio, media

How would i make it so in my program there is a button when that button is clicked i want it to play a .wma file without opening and media player?

Answer (score 19):

The C++ standard does not include this functionality. That means it depends on what your system offers.

For Windows, you can try something like [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712879.aspx).

However, you best bet is to use a pre-existing library, like:

- [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx)
- [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/)
- [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/)
- [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)'s: [Sound](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html).

Searching for [C++ Sound Library](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=C%2B%2B+Sound+Library) brings up a lot of information.

Also, check out these three other [SO topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+play+sound):

- [What Is The Best C++ Sound API For Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314522/what-is-the-best-c-sound-api-for-windows)
- [How to play MP3 files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428884/how-to-play-mp3-files-in-c)
- [Learning to work with audio in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711350/learning-to-work-with-audio-in-c)

Comment: Playsound doesn't play .wma files, only .wav.

Answer (score 2):

Although the above answer mentions it (and everything else, it doesn't give any recommendations so...), FMOD is the king of C++ sound (the most used) and works great so I'd recommend FMOD in particular.

Answer (score 1):

[Gstreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) is a free, cross-platform multimedia framework written in C (using [GObject](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/)) that allows encoding/decoding for many types of media, including wma. Very easy to use and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

KDE's [Phonon](http://phonon.kde.org/) is a cross-platform(!) C++ multimedia library. It supports native sound systems as backends. Worth a look if you haven't seen it before, and a simple video player can be written in a mere 83 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, in all honesty your best bet is DirectShow.  The RenderFile API allows you to play most audio file types with just a few lines of code.

The best part about DirectShow is that it's a part of the Windows platform so you don't need to bundle an external component.