# C/C++ library for .wav file encoding

Tags: c++, audio, wav, pcm

I need a library for MS VC6 which encodes sampled data which is in the form of a float array, to an audio file format preferably wav
Also is there a library that can encode the samples into pcm form and play it directly through the sound card without saving a wav file first??

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451606/programably-make-and-play-a-sound-through-speakers-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the WAV file format is very simple.  To just play the samples, use the waveOut functions; they're documented.

To convert from a float to a signed 16-bit PCM sample, just convert the sample into the 16 bit range.  For example, assuming a sample in the range -1.0 to +1.0 multiply by 32767.0 and convert to an integer:

```
int16_t sample = static_cast<int16_t>(32767.0 * float_sample);
```

Once you have those, just use the waveOut* functions to play the samples.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) (www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) and [SndLib](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/sndlib/) (ccrma.stanford.edu/software/snd/sndlib/) will do what you want.