# Play sound on certain speaker - c++

Tags: c++, audio

Which free C++ audio library could I use to play sounds(mainly sines) on a certain speaker, in a stereo system ? I know I could create sounds that play only on the left/right channel, and then simply play these, but this doesn't help me. My target is to play a frequency on the left speaker, and another frequency on the right one.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning to work with audio in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711350/learning-to-work-with-audio-in-c)

Comment: Create a stereo sound with different data on different channels. Before this question is closed, check the FMOD.

Answer (score 1):

You might give idea about your OS. Anyhow have a look at following list of libraries:

1. [Free Sound and Audio Libraries](http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/soundlib.html) - set of crossplatform OpenSource audio libraries.
2. [CLAM - (C++ Library for Audio and Music)](http://clam-project.org/) -  is a full-fledged software framework for research and application development in the Audio and Music Domain. It offers a conceptual model as well as tools for the analysis, synthesis and processing of audio signals.
3. [Kowalski](http://code.google.com/p/kowalski/) - [Description of project](https://github.com/stuffmatic/kowalski#kowalski)Windows/OSX/iOS.
4. [Soundtouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) -  is an open-source audio processing library for changing the Tempo, Pitch and Playback Rates of audio streams or audio files
5. [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/) - is an audio library for use in software on several platforms. Its purpose is to provide developers with powerful and efficient sample, stream (MP3, MP2, MP1, OGG, WAV, AIFF, custom generated, and more via OS codecs and add-ons), MOD music (XM, IT, S3M, MOD, MTM, UMX), MO3 music (MP3/OGG compressed MODs), and recording functions. All in a compact DLL that won't bloat your distribution.

To use Stereo under Windows have a look at this [sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11184/The-ultimate-Managed-DirectSound-9-Tutorial-Part-1)